# Idiomatic way to config loggers

Tags: python, logging

What would be the *most pythonic* approach to initialize/config loggers?

```py
# logger.py
def initialize_loggers():
    with open("logging.json") as fl:
        logging.config.dictConfig(json.load(fl))
```

I see three possible options:

- call `initialize_loggers()` inside `__init__.py`
- call `initialize_loggers()` inside `logger.py`

  - even if *multiple modules* import it, initialization will *occur once*
- call `initialize_loggers()` explicitly in *every* file, protected by `__name__ == "__main__"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Applications* are responsible for configuring loggers. Libraries simply *use* loggers configured by whatever application is using them.

`initialize_loggers` should be called at (or near the start of) the entry point to an application. If a file is not going to be used as a script, it has no reason to call it. As such, your third option is the closest to what you should do.